# Connect to Oracle SQL DB using JDBC connection

Tags: qgis, sql, database, oracle-spatial, connection

My IP address changes frequently and hence I use ssh tunnel via bastion host to connect to Oracle SQL DB. I used JDBC to connect to the Oracle SQL and it works successfully. However, I want to connect to Oracle DB from my QGIS and I tried adding a new connection using Layer -> Vector Layer -> selected Database radio button. When I tested my connection I got the below error.

Are the procedures for connecting QGIS to Oracle SQL directly and for connecting QGIS to Oracle via tunneling using JDBC is the same?

[image]

I set up tunnel in SQL Developer as below:
[image]

And in the tns_names file I added port forwarding as follows:

`(prdatp_tp = (description= (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-tokyo-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=gact2d7ku0cfecu_prdatp_tp.atp.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn= "CN=adb.ap-tokyo-1.oraclecloud.com,OU=Oracle ADB TOKYO,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Redwood City,ST=California,C=US"))   ))`

In the sqlnet.ora I provided the path to my wallet folder:
`WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="C:/Users/Swathi V/Wallet_prdatp_and_devatp"))) SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes`

I am able to successfully connect to the SQL Oracle DB via bastion host using the above-explained configuration. Coming to QGIS the following is the screenshot of a new connection I tried to create, for which I got an error:
[image]

Comment: We need details of how you set up your tunnel and what **exactly** you put in the QGIS connection box

Comment: @IanTurton I have edited my question to include the complete details of the connection.

Comment: That is not the correct way to access an Oracle DB (or use a tunnel) - see https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#connecting-to-oracle-spatial but basically your host should be `ssh_prdpt` and the database should be the actual name of the database (and JDBC is completly wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is what worked for me.

These are the details I entered in the new Oracle connection dialog:

**Name:** Any name you like to give for your connection

**Database:** ssh_prdatp_tp_1523

Please note that this is the name of the connection defined in my 'tns_names' file.

**Port:** 1521

In my 'tns_names' file, I have the below connection defined:
*ssh_prdatp_tp_1523 =(description= (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1523)(host=localhost))(connect_data=(service_name=gact2d7ku0cfecu_prdatp_tp.atp.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.ap-tokyo-1.oraclecloud.com,OU=Oracle ADB TOKYO,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Redwood City,ST=California,C=US")))*

For the authentication credentials, I just used "Basic" option as shown in the screenshot below:[image]

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out and I hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 2):

Please find in the image attached how I have defined in QGIS the connection to an Oracle Autonomous Database.
Please note:

- You need to download and extract the wallet into the folder defined in the parameter
  "wallet_location".
- The parameters "https_proxy" and "https_proxy_port" you need to set if you want to connect via VPN.
- From what I have observed, the checkboxes underneath the "Authentication" dialog don't seem to work properly. But I might be wrong.

Regards,
Karin

[image: QGIS connection to an Autonomous DB]