# Oracle connection in QGIS 3 with proxy user

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

Following a somewhat similar discussion ([Connect to Oracle SQL DB using JDBC connection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404141/connect-to-oracle-sql-db-using-jdbc-connection)), I'd like to ask what I'm not doing right, with my QGIS Oracle connection setup.

I have SQLDeveloper configured to be connected through a proxy user (following DB security requirements), Using a TNS connection type like below:

[image]

No problem with SQLDeveloper to connect.
With QGIS instead, if I try to replicate this type of connection
I get a

```
ORA-01017 invalid username password
```

How should I setup the proxy-user connection in QGIS?
Should I setup a JDBC string but if so, how?

Note also how, in order to make the SQLDeveloper connection work, I had to setup SQLDeveloper preferences so to use an external Oracle client (instantclient) and the Thick/OCI driver. Also, compatibility with the Oracle client needs to be taken care of. DB is an Oracle 12g; Oracle instant client 21.11; SQLDeveloper 21.4.1. I wonder if such setup is feasible in QGIS.